# Swap the array in single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swap

I know this is very silly question. But, I'm very eager to know how to swap the elements in a single line.

Ex:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

I need the answer like this

```
a, b = 2, 1
```

Comment: Why the one line requirement?  I can see playing around with it for fun, but it solves no real problem.

Comment: @ED, Yeah, it's so funny question. But, Your thoughts and ideas are help to solve some other problems in my project.

Comment: Ok, well, I threw up a response.  I should get back to work =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a,b = b,a    # does work....

irb(main):017:0* a, b = 1, 2
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):018:0> a
=> 1
irb(main):019:0> b
=> 2
irb(main):020:0> a, b = b,a
=> [2, 1]
irb(main):021:0> a
=> 2
irb(main):022:0> b
=> 1
irb(main):023:0>
```

Comment: that you mean, Is it possible or not?.

Comment: My answer was right. I then thought it was wrong. I was mistaken, my original answer was right.

Comment: @Mr Black: The answer proves that it is possible!

Comment: :) Yes, Thanks. I revert back my words.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to swap an array in your title, yet not in your example. I'm going with the title, so...

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
x.reverse!
=> [5,4,3,2,1]
```

You could also do this... I guess...

```
a, b = 1, 2
a, b = b, a
```

Comment: They have their place.  Why allocate a new array when all you want to do is reverse the existing one?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do

```
array[0, 1] = array[1, 0]
```

Comment: No, that's a slice, and it doesn't expand to *n* elements.